# why executing docker log -f it returns data from scratch?

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have a simple code in Dotnet core console and it simply counted forever :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int counter = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            counter++;
            Console.WriteLine(counter);
        }
    }
}
```

I contained it with docker and ran it via VS Docker run.

but every time that I execute > **docker logs -f  dockerID** it starts and shows counting from scratch! (1,2,3,....). I expected that whenever I run this command it shows me logs from the last integer that it counts!

Is "docker logs -f" cause to run a new instance of my application every time?

Comment: You need a Volume to  preserve data generated by the running container. The volumes are stored on the host, independent of the container life cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running `docker help logs` you see this:

```
--tail string    Number of lines to show from the end of the logs
                 (default "all")
```

So you should do:

```
docker logs --tail 100 -f dockerID
```

Additional reference: [docker logs documentation > Options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/#options)

Answer (score 0):

`docker logs -f` should work similar to `tail -f`, so, it should show just new logs.
Therefore, if you're watching logs repeated, it looks your program is being executed in loop.

The only thing that comes to my mind is a little trick, although it's not an elegant solution, it can be useful for other similar situations:

1. Define in your system history time format according to `docker logs`

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S "
```

2. Get your last docker logs command date with a simple script.

```
LAST_DOCKER_LOG=`history | grep " docker logs" | tac | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'`
```

3. Get logs after your last `docker logs` execution:

```
docker logs --since $LAST_DOCKER_LOG <your_docker>
```

In one line:

```
docker logs -t --since `history | grep " docker logs" | tac | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'` <your_docker>
```

> Note: history time and docker log times have to be in the same timezone.

In spite of everything, I'd have a look to your loop execution. Maybe, `docker log -t` timestamp show option can help you to solve it.